# Порядок выполнения git commit и git pull

Tags: git, git-commit, git-pull

Недавно начал работать с гитом.
Какая разница сделать `pull` до `commit` или после `commit`, и есть ли она вообще?

Comment: А какая связь? Эти команды делают совершенно разные слабо связанные действия. Может надо учебник почитать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В целом разницы нет. Если конфликта в ваших изменениях и изменениях из upstream не будет, то все пройдет без вопросов. Если же возникнет конфликт слияния, git так или иначе сообшит об этом, и вам в любом случае придется его решать.

Но я бы предпочел сначала сделать коммит, чтобы зафиксировать изменения. Тогда легко можно будет откатиться к исходной версии ваших изменений, если что-то пойдет не так.

Если коммит по каким-то причинам делать не хочется (например, работа не завершена), можно временно спрятать изменения командой `git stash`, потом сделать `git pull`, а потом вернуть изменения командой `git stash apply`. Этому посвящен отдельный [раздел в документации](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5).

Comment: Всё именно так, но я как раз сначала бы сделал git pull. Привычка постоянно жать get latest version. В 99% смерджится автоматом, а если не смерджится -- то это лишний повод посмотреть, насколько прилетевший коммит влияет на твою работу и не нужно ли её переделать (а то и вовсе отменить -- да, иногда бывало и так).

Comment: @Alex если вам помог ответ, отметьте его как принятый, пожалуйста.